# No registered env with id: BanditTenArmedGaussian-v0 for the package gym_bandits of OpenAI

Tags: openai-gym

I've made the following instruction :

```
git clone https://github.com/JKCooper2/gym-bandits.git
cd gym-bandits
pip install -e .
```

After installing :

```
import gym_bandits
import gym
```

Now we finally :

```
env = gym.make("BanditTenArmedGaussian-v0")
```

Even tough the first three steps was successfull, the last one doesn't work. Here is my error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\windows\system32\gym\gym\envs\registration.py in spec(self, path)
    120         try:
--> 121             return self.env_specs[id]
    122         except KeyError:

KeyError: 'BanditTenArmedGaussian-v0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnregisteredEnv                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-645d2b1dfa73> in <module>
      4 import math
      5 import random
----> 6 env = gym.make("BanditTenArmedGaussian-v0")

c:\windows\system32\gym\gym\envs\registration.py in make(id, **kwargs)
    143 
    144 def make(id, **kwargs):
--> 145     return registry.make(id, **kwargs)
    146 
    147 def spec(id):

c:\windows\system32\gym\gym\envs\registration.py in make(self, path, **kwargs)
     87         else:
     88             logger.info('Making new env: %s', path)
---> 89         spec = self.spec(path)
     90         env = spec.make(**kwargs)
     91         # We used to have people override _reset/_step rather than

c:\windows\system32\gym\gym\envs\registration.py in spec(self, path)
    129                 raise error.DeprecatedEnv('Env {} not found (valid versions include {})'.format(id, matching_envs))
    130             else:
--> 131                 raise error.UnregisteredEnv('No registered env with id: {}'.format(id))
    132 
    133     def register(self, id, **kwargs):

UnregisteredEnv: No registered env with id: BanditTenArmedGaussian-v0
```

Does anyone know how to fix it ?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

The standard installation of OpenAI environments does **not** support Windows. See the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/11).

To get that code to run, you'll have to switch another operating system (i.e., Linux or Mac) or use a [non-standard installation](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-install-openai-gym-in-a-windows-environment-338969e24d30).

Comment: Or use google's Colab platform. Here is the link https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aoqoSRFy6ThXD4W9yMnWrmZzbO3fuUnY

Comment: It works ! Thank you can you write it as an answer I'll give you +50.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that when calling `env = gym.make("BanditTenArmedGaussian-v0")`, you also import the `gym_bandits` in same code. Otherwise, gym has problems to find the right package.